# How to create a Custom action to change content type properties value and add user rights

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

How can I create a custom action that changes the value of the content type properties and assigns user rights? I'm using AIO 4.0. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already worked through the [tutorials on ECM Architect](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series)? It starts with the SDK, moves on to content types, and then custom actions followed by behaviors, web scripts, and workflow. By the time you work through the actions tutorial you'll know how to write custom actions that can specialize the type of an object and set properties.

I don't think any of the tutorials set permissions, but my [Alfresco ACL Templates](https://github.com/Conexiam/alfresco-acl-templates/blob/master/acl-templates-repo/src/main/java/com/conexiam/acl/templates/service/AclTemplateServiceImpl.java) project has some good examples for working with the Permission Service from Java.